# Thinkpad X230 touchpad scroll momentum (inertial scrolling) doesn't work, how to enable it? Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Tags: xorg, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I can't use momentum scroll (also called inertial scrolling, when it keeps scrolling after giving an acceleration) on my touchpad. It seems to be disabled and I can't enable it.

I've searched on internet and tried to install xserver-xorg-input-syaptics, this enable the momentum scroll but then I can't change any touchpad settings on Settings>Mouse because touchpad options seems disappeared. 
I have to remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics to make my touchpad options available again on settings.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
Device Enabled (139):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Tapping Enabled (276): 1
libinput Tapping Enabled Default (277): 0
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (278):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (279):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (280):   0
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (281):   0
libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (282):  1, 0
libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (283):  1, 0
libinput Accel Speed (284): 0.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (285): 0.000000
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (286):   1
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (287):   0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (261): 1, 1
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (262):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (263):    0, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (288): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (289): 0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (290):    1, 1, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (291):   1, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (292):   1, 0, 0
libinput Click Methods Available (293): 1, 1
libinput Click Method Enabled (294):    1, 0
libinput Click Method Enabled Default (295):    1, 0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (296):    0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (297):    0
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (298):    1
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (299):    1
Device Node (264):  "/dev/input/event5"
Device Product ID (265):    2, 7
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (300):   <no items>
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (301):   1
```

Comment: What is momentum scroll?

Comment: Is when it keeps scrolling with some inertia, depending on how much acceleration you give.

Comment: It is not supported in `libinput`, but is supported with `synaptics`. The settings should work with `synaptics` unless you are using a non-standard Ubuntu version.

Comment: `libinput` is not installed, if I use   `xinput` it displays  `SynPS/2 Synaptics Touchpad`.  So I'm currently using synaptics driver even with  `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` removed.

Comment: You confuse the touchpad name and the user space driver. Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput list-props ID`, where `ID` is the id of your touchpad from the `xinput` command.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I've updated my question.